# Converting array in Json PHP output not as expected

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv

I have some problem when I convert an PHP array to Json. for more contex this is the code:

`<?php

```
$Users = array();
$file = fopen('usersFile.csv', 'r');
$row = fgets($file);
$ColumnKeys = explode(',', $row);
while (!feof($file)) {
    $row = fgets($file);
    $userData = explode(',', $row);
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($columnkeys); $i++) { 
        $user[$columnKeys[$i]] = $userData[$i];
    }
    array_push($Users, $user);
}
fclose($file);
echo json_encode($Users);
```

?>`

The csv file containing the user data is this:

id,name,docNumber,dateBirth

1,Mario Mario,1694370,06/11/1953

2,Pau Pep,1725614,24/04/1964

The output look like this:

`[{"id":"1","name":"Mario Mario","docNumber":"1694370","dateBirth\r\n":"06\11\1953\r\n"}, {"id":"2","name":"Pau Pep","docNumber":"1725614","dateBirth\r\n":"24\04\1964\r\n"}]`

I don't know why in the output the $Users array contain Metacharacter in the dateBirth and their value. Is driving me mad.

Comment: I'd suggest just trimming the keys and values. Those are newline characters.

Comment: Try trimming the last 4 characters.

Comment: Also look at `fgetcsv` and `array_combine`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is an option for json_encode called   JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

```
<?php
$Users = array();
$file = fopen('usersFile.csv', 'r');
$row = fgets($file);
$columnKeys = explode(',', trim($row));
while (!feof($file)) {
    $row = fgets($file);
    $userData = explode(',', trim($row));
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($columnKeys); $i++) { 
        $user[$columnKeys[$i]] = $userData[$i];
    }
    array_push($Users, $user);
}
fclose($file);
echo json_encode($Users, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Mario Mario","docNumber":"1694370","dateBirth":"06/11/1953"},{"id":"2","name":"Pau Pep","docNumber":"1725614","dateBirth":"24/04/1964"}]
```